# Get integer value from another class

Tags: objective-c, ios, inheritance, integer

I know i have done this before, but I just cant remember how to do it.

I have a integer, that i want to be able to change in another class of mine.

how do i do it?

```
MainViewClass : UIViewController {
int score;
}


#import "MainViewClass.h"
OtherClass : MainViewClass{

}
```

Then in the .m of OtherClass i want to be able to use the variable score.

How do i do this?

I have searched around the internet, and have tried several things to try to get it to work will no success.

Thanks for looking!
Have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your MainViewClass.h, you'll want to add your int as a property of that class.

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int score;
```

Then in your MainViewClass.m, you'll want to synthesize the property using:

```
@synthesize score;
```

Now since your subclassing MainViewClass in your OtherClass you can access it's properties using some combination of the following.

In your OtherClass.h add

MainViewClass *mainViewClass;

in your OtherClass.m wherever you need access to the score, you should be able to access it as such.

```
mainViewClass = (MainViewClass *) self.parent;
```

and then the score using,

```
mainViewClass.score;
```

Answer (score 4):

In your example, `int score` is an *instance variable*, or *ivar* for short. It's a piece of data associated with any given instance of `MainViewClass`. By default, and for good reason, instance variables have `@protected` visibility, meaning that only `MainViewClass` and its subclasses can access it.

Now, you made `OtherClass` a subclass of `MainViewClass` in your example, which means to access `score` from *the same object* you need only type `score` or `self->score`, and from another object that is a `MainViewClass` you need only type `theOtherObject->score`. (This sort of design *exposes implementation details* and so is often considered to be bad design by many coders, but for a simple use case like this you can probably get away with it. *Why* it's bad is a discussion that has raged for *decades* and is beyond the scope of this question.)

Answer (score 2):

You create getter and setter methods (or a property with synthesized accessors) in the class with the integer, give the other class a reference to some instance of the first class, and have it use those accessors to get and set the integer.