# Get UIView property value in UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiview, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have a CustomView(**subclass of UIView**) with some odd UIButtons in it, which gets displayed when a button on ViewController is clicked. How i can get button's tag value set in CustomView in my ViewController.

CustomView.m
- I will set button tag = 005

ViewController.m
- How can i get 005 here?

I went through below SO posts, but not getting how to implement it.
[LINK1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679216/ios-protocol-delegate-confusion) [LINK2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639027/get-integer-value-from-another-class)

Comment: Have you got any reference to CustomView in ViewController?

Comment: @Greg No.I am using [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:] in ViewController.m

Answer (score 0):

If you have reference to your CustomView in ViewController you can do something like that:

```
for (UIView *v in self.customView.subviews) {
    if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        int tag = v.tag;
    }
}
```

However if you haven't got any references to the custom view try this:

```
for (UIView *v in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([v isKindOfClass:[CustomView class]]) {
        CustomView customView = (CustomView*)v;
        for (UIView *v1 in customView.subviews) {
            if ([v1 isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
                int tag = v.tag;
                break; // You have the tag exit loop
            }
        }
        break; // you have custom view exit loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use delegates or anything. You just need a reference to the CustomView in the ViewController then use something like:

```
for (UIView *view in [_myCustomView subviews]) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:([UIButton class])]) { 
        //Test the tag
        if (view.tag == 5) {
            //found it! do something with it.
            break;
        }
     }
}
```

to add a reference in the view controller add this to the @interface part of your .m file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CustomView* myCustomView;
```

then, when you create the custom viee, assign it to myCustomView like this:

```
_myCustomView = [[CustomView alloc] init...];
```